# How can I add a desktop/GUI to a command-line Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gui

I had installed Ubuntu on a VM, with a command-line only interface, now I have had enough of command-line interface experience and plan to proceed with GUI mode.

But I dont want to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu with GUI mode; I want my current [CLI] to have GUI.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed as CLI, and desired to have some light-weight (less resource consuming, slow-system friendly) GUI.

What are my options and how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a fully-functional desktop environment, there are lightweight ones available. Here are some, in approximate order of increasing resource consumption:

- [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) (install [`lubuntu-desktop`](http://lubuntu.net/))
- [Xfce](http://xfce.org/) (install [`xubuntu-desktop`](http://xubuntu.org/))
- [GNOME Fallback](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gnome-3-fallback.html) (a.k.a. "GNOME Classic") (install [`gnome-session-fallback`](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed))
- Unity 2D (install `ubuntu-desktop` and pick Ubuntu 2D as your session type)

If you want to go lighter-weight than any of that, you can manually install the `xorg` package, and a lightweight window manager like [`openbox`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Openbox) or [`fluxbox`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fluxbox) ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI#X11_Server_Installation)).

Answer (score 3):

Install LXDE, a fast and light-weight GUI that runs on openbox. You can do that by typing `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` on the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have problem with having tiling window managers, I suggest you to install DWM (by suckless) or Awesome. They are damn light and fast(quite less time to load). They seem a bit geeky for new users though. Other traditional light weight systems are there which I don't have first hand experience with. First few links in a web search should help you though.