# Massive error! x-nautilus-desktop:///

Tags: 12.04, command-line

Im getting this error once I start up by netbook running ubuntu 12.04 about "x-nautilus-desktop:///". There's no desktop, lags horribly and the bar at the top of the screen's blank anyways to fix it without reimaging it? Here more on what it said...

Error: DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gtk.vfs.Daemon was not provided by any .service files
Please select another viewer and try again.

I listened to Elder Geek and now can access the terminal, now what?

Comment: You should be able to get to a terminal prompt by holding down <CTRL> & <ALT> and tapping F1. Please provide the full error regarding "x-nautilus-desktop:///"

Comment: Alright, I edited the post explaining in a little more detail on the problem, yes I can now get into the terminal...so now what?

Comment: This is a DBUS problem I found an answer for this under Debian here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=37040 you may find it simpler to reinstall the desktop as outlined in my answer below

Comment: The normal terminal has a password on it that I did not set and the one you told me to get to also needs a password I never set. It was different originally :\

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I thought when you said you could get into the terminal that you could login to the terminal. If you can't use your password that is a different question which has been answered http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

Now that you can get into the terminal try the best answer here:
[How can I add a desktop/GUI to a command-line Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149058/how-can-i-add-a-desktop-gui-to-a-command-line-ubuntu-installation)

```
sudo apt-get install <desktop of choice from above>
```